# Why doesn't == return false here?

Tags: lua

I don't understand why this happens.

```
function findVar()
    local i = string.find(equation, "%a")
    var = string.sub(equation, i, i)
    while true do
        i = string.find(equation, "%a", i + 1)
        if i == nil then break end
        check = string.sub(equation, i, i)
        if not var == check then
            quit("Error. Multiple variables.", true)
        end
    end
end
```

This code is supposed to find the variable in an equation, which it does, but then it needs to find a variable that isn't the same as the 1st variable. If found, it should terminate the script. The problem is, that when it does find a variable that differs the 1st one, it doesn't terminate anything.

I have tried changing the *check* variable to global.

Comment: There's no `return` nor any arguments (what's `equation`?). Also, `not var == check` is parsed as `(not var) == check`, which cannot be true since `check` is a string whereas `not var` is a boolean; do you mean `var ~= check`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like InSync stated, `==` is consistently returning false when comparing `not var` with `check`.

[~=](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.5) would be more suitable ie `var ~= check`.

Brackets like `not (var == check)` could work too.